# symfony : how to make a validator for unique key?

Tags: forms, symfony1, unique-key

I want to know how I can make a validator for a key which must be unique.

Comment: Symfony version, please (validators are implemented differently in 1.0/1.1 and 1.2+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sfValidatorDoctrineUnique or sfValidatorPropelUnique is probably what you're looking for even though you didn't describe it in very much detail:

*sfValidatorDoctrineUnique*: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatordoctrineunique

*sfValidatorPropelUnique*: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatorpropelunique

Comment: Thanks, It's the validator I searched.